# First. and Last . in sas

Tags: sas

My data table looks like :

```
Name Amount Status
a 5000 Debit
a 2000 Credit
a 1000 Credit
b 2000 Debit
b 1000 Debit
b 1000 Credit
```

I want my output to be:

```
Name net_amount status
a 2000 Debit
b 2000 Debit
```

How can I achieve it using `first.` and `last.` variables?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Suggest you show what code you have tried so far.

Comment: According to the raw data that you wrote, it's impossible to gain that output (with a single statement obviousbly).
With first. or last, you will output a raw tagged as first or last of a series according to the by statement specified (be sure to prior sort a dataset.).
The first row in your output dataset is not included in the source dataset.
Please, always post your attempt, also if poor.

Comment: What logic have you used to select the contents of the two rows in the example output above? Unless state the logic clearly and explicitly you can't be sure that any answer you receive will behave as you expect in all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

```
data a;
input Name $ Amount Status $;
cards;
a 5000 Debit
a 2000 Credit
a 1000 Credit
b 2000 Debit
b 1000 Debit
b 1000 Credit
;
run;

proc sort data=a; 
by name status amount; 
run;

data by_name_first_obs by_name_and_status_first_obs
     by_name_last_obs by_name_and_status_last_obs;
set a;
by name status;
if first.name then output by_name_first_obs;
if last.name then output by_name_last_obs;
if first.status then output by_name_and_status_first_obs;
if last.status then output by_name_and_status_last_obs;
run;
```